# No signature of method (or how to add a third-party library) in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I have Android Studio 0.5.8. Here is my `build.gradle` file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'

    }

}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

  dependencies {
    compile files('libs/scala-compiler.jar', 'libs/scala-library.jar', 'libs/scala-reflect.jar')
  }
}
```

I added the libs manually because right-mouse-click on the *.jar didn't cause to add the line `compile files`. But I'm getting the error now:

```
Error: No signature of method: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.compile() is applicable for argument types: (org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultConfigurableFileCollection) values: [file collection]
Possible solutions: module(java.lang.Object)
```

How do I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the dependencies block from the build file you posted in your question. Instead, add the library dependencies from the Project Structure dialog. In that dialog, choose the module you want to add dependencies for, select the Dependencies tab, click the + button, and choose "File dependency":

[image: Project Structure dialog showing the option to add a file dependency]

Having said that, if you've started your project in the last few months on anything approaching a recent version of Android Studio, it should automatically be picking up any libraries that are in the libs directory inside your module, via the line:

{dir=libs, include=[*.jar]}

If that line is present and it's not seeing the libraries, then perhaps you've put them in the wrong folder -- there's a libs directory inside your module where they should go. You may have to click the "Sync Project with Gradle Files" button in the toolbar to pick them up.

Comment: I have that line. How do I know they've gotten picked up? do they have to appear automatically in "dependencies" tab or in build.gradle?